# show discount price on product view after apply coupon code by url

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, product-list, product-view

i wrote an extension to auto apply coupon codes by url. this works great.
now i want to redirect to an url specified by myself where one or some products for this coupon are shown. so my question is: is it possible to process a cart rule on product list.phtml or view.phtml?

my idea is to overwrite `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price,` here is my class:

```
public function getPrice($product) {
    $coupon_code = trim(Mage::getSingleton("checkout/session")->getData("coupon_code"));
    if ($coupon_code != '') {
        $oCoupon = Mage::getModel('salesrule/coupon')->loadByCode($coupon_code);
        $salesRule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($oCoupon->getRuleId());

        $item = new Varien_Object();
        $item->setProduct($product);

        $isValid = (bool) $salesRule->getActions()->validate($item);

        if ($isValid === true) {
            //here i want to process the coupon code so the originalPrice and the discountPrice are shown on price box
        }
    }

    return $product->getData("price");
}
```

is there a way to solve my problem? maybe i did search for the wrong keywords on google ;) could you give me a hint :)

Thx :)